# Get URL of Internet Explorer pop-up

Tags: internet-explorer, url, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm using CRM and want to run a dialog screen without having to go into CRM, I want to be able to get the URL of the popup that opens when a dialog screen is ran so that I can copy that URL into a shortcut, however, when the Dialog box opens there is no visible URL. When I right click to try get into settings I'm only given basic options which I have provided in the screenshot below

Does anyone know how to find the URL of the dialog box?

[image: Screenshot up popup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328483.aspx) describes the format for URL addressable components in CRM including Forms, Views and Dialogs.

The one you're after is:

> [organization url]/cs/dialog/rundialog.aspx?DialogId=[dialog unique
>   identifier]&EntityName=[entity logical name]&ObjectId=[unique
>   identifier for the record]

Google is your friend.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I just found a unusual way of achieving what I wanted, in my screenshot you'll notice a little arrow on the right that will make the tip box disappear, when the mouse is over the arrow a URL appeared in the bottom of the screen, then by clicking the mouse wheel button it opened the form in a Internet Explorer window where the URL was then present to copy and paste